# how do i fill a column in the table using cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

subj. I get the ID, and it will fill the table. But in this example, only the last entry is filled. 
If you announce in page_load "pro = number" - that is filled correctly.
What to do please tell me.

```
  public string idul;
            public int pro;
            public string nz;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

         protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          pro = 5;
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = pro; i > -1; i--)
            {
                wisp();
            }


        }
        public void wisp()
        {
SqlConnection con_tsp = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JJ"].ConnectionString);
                string tsp1 = "UPDATE TSP SET IDUL=@IDUL WHERE NZ=@NZ";
                SqlCommand upd_tsp = new SqlCommand(tsp1, con_tsp);

                upd_tsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NZ", pro);
                upd_tsp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDUL", "12");

                upd_tsp.Connection.Open();
                upd_tsp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                upd_tsp.Connection.Close();

                pro--;



        }
```

Comment: Two `Button2_Click` handlers? Which one is being called?

Comment: my mistake, corrected the code to be pasted. The first button name Button1_Click.

Comment: So when `Button1` is clicked you set a variable during a round-trip to the server. What do you expect the value to be when `Button2` is clicked (hint: another round-trip to the server...)? Solution: Unless you store `pro` in the session, the value you set in `Button1_Click` is lost when you press `Button2_Click` as ASP pages are stateless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set Pro as a global variable, on Button2_Click the value will be set to 0 (int's default value)
and then the button click handler will be called hence u r getting only 0 as the input value

Comment: Karthik Ganesan, Thank you.